# object instantiation in main() or object instantiation within constructor. Which one is better and why?

Tags: java, constructor, interface, instantiation

I am new to Java. When I learn the interface concept and implementation of Java, I noticed there are two approaches for the example code, which bugged my head for a while. Because the instructor was saying that the main purpose of dependency injection (constructor injection method) is to insert a layer between implementation and instantiation on `this.calculator = new TaxCalculator2020(100000);`in **original TaxReport.java**. I have two questions regarding to this example code. 1.In the **Main.java by me** without using interface, which method is preferred and why? 2.I noticed that **interface TaxReport.java** and **Taxreport.java by me** are very similar code-wise so that I am having trouble to understand concept of using interface. I'd really appreciate that someone can name a circumstance in this example code that interface actually helps.

original Main.java:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        var report1 = new TaxReport();

        report1.show();
    }
}
```

original TaxCalculator2020.java:

```
public class TaxCalculator2020 implements TaxCalculator {
    private double taxableIncome;

    public TaxCalculator2020(double taxableIncome) {
        this.taxableIncome = taxableIncome;
    }

    public double calculateTax(){
        return taxableIncome*0.3;
    }
}
```

original TaxReport.java:

```
public class TaxReport {
    private TaxCalculator2020 calculator;

    public TaxReport(){
        this.calculator = new TaxCalculator2020(100000);
    }
    public void show(){
        var tax = calculator.calculateTax();
        System.out.println(tax);
    }
}
```

interface Main.java:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        var calculator = new TaxCalculator2020(100000);
        var report1 = new TaxReport(calculator);

        report1.show();
    }
}
```

interface TaxReport.java:

```
public class TaxReport {
    private TaxCalculator calculator;

    public TaxReport(TaxCalculator calculator){
        this.calculator = calculator;
    }
    public void show(){
        var tax = calculator.calculateTax();
        System.out.println(tax);
    }
}
```

And lastly Interface TaxCalculator.java

```
public interface TaxCalculator {
    double calculateTax();
}
```

The example code is kinda awkward in my opinion because I am having trouble to understand interface with it. So following is my version of code that contains the two approaches without using interface:

Main.java by me:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        var calculator = new TaxCalculator2020(100000);

        var report1 = new TaxReport(calculator);         //instantiate within main()
        var report2 = new TaxReport(100000);             //instantiate within constructor

        report1.show();
        report2.show();
    }
}
```

TaxReport.java by me:

```
public class TaxReport {
    private TaxCalculator2020 calculator;

    public TaxReport(TaxCalculator2020 calculator){
        this.calculator = calculator;
    }
    public TaxReport(double taxableIncome){
        this.calculator = new TaxCalculator2020(taxableIncome);
    }
    public void show(){
        var tax = calculator.calculateTax();
        System.out.println(tax);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For the first question, the use of interface is not justified in the example given in the tutorial which you are referring. An **interface** provides way to define one template and use it for providing different implementations for different classes. For example:

   ```
    public interface TaxCalculator{
        double calculateTax();
    }

    public class Tax2020 implements TaxCalculator{
        double calculateTax()
        {
           ------ logic
        }
    }

    public class Tax2021 implements TaxCalculator{
        double calculateTax()
        {
            -------- other logic
        }
    }
   ```

Also, we use interfaces for implementing Multiple Inheritance in Java.

2. Regarding second question, the meaning of **dependency injection** is to shift the dependency to other objects.

   ```
    public SomeClass() {
      myObject = Factory.getObject();
    }
   ```

In above case, to do some testing on SomeClass, if I need myObject class with complex logic, then we need to do mock the functionality for it, but we can avoid that by using Constructor based dependency injection or setter based injection.

```
    public SomeClass (MyClass myObject) {
    this.myObject = myObject;
    }
```

So, it is preferred to have constructor based dependency.